# Guardar datos en dos tablas diferentes con formularios en Django

Tags: python, django

Buen día estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual deseo editar el perfil del usuario Soy nuevo en Django es mi primer proyecto es una actividad, tengo un formulario que hereda de Form no de ModelForm

```
class FormEditProfile(forms.Form):
first_name = forms.CharField(label='Tu nombre', max_length=30)
last_name = forms.CharField(label='Tu Apellido', max_length=120)
date = forms.DateField(label='Fecha de Nacimiento')
email = forms.EmailField(label='Correo Electronico', max_length=100)
bio = forms.CharField(label='Biofrafía', widget=forms.Textarea, max_length=1000)
photo = forms.ImageField(label='Foto de Perfil')
```

Estoy utilizando la tabla de django por defecto y le e agregado otros campos:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

date_time = models.DateField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='user', default='user/user.png')
bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
usuid = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.usuid.username, self.date_time, self.photo, self.bio)
```

Mi preguntas es como puedo acceder a los campos y como los puedo guardar dependiendo de el usuario que esté logueado, y por supuesto como puedo especificar que campo va a que tabla ya que los campos **bio**, **photo** y **date_time** no son de django intente dando valores vacios a estos campos una vez se haya logueado por primera vez pero esto no sirve ya que necesito es que el usuario pueda editarlos el mismo no yo darle valores, espero su ayuda muchísimas gracias, si aun no he aclarado algo por favor diganmelo, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si puedo ayudarte porque no entiendo muy bien tu problema, ¿lo que quieres hacer es que el usuario al rellenar el formulario, se guarden los datos en la clase Profile?

Suponiendo que es así te diré como lo haria yo:

Los datos que enviás desde un formulario a la url que elijas al declarar dicho formulario en el template se envian mediante **POST** y con el **request** dentro de las funciones recoges esos datos.

El request aparte de los datos del formulario contiene mas datos, para acceder específicamente al POST tienes que poner: **request.POST**
Con esto estas accediendo al POST, ahora con el metodo get decides que campo recoger.

Ej:
**request.POST.get('photo', None)** ó  **request.POST.get('bio', None)**

Ahora para guardar los datos en la tabla, solo tienes que guardar un objeto de la clase Profile:

Ej:

```
Profile(date_time=datetime.datetime.now,
photo=request.POST.get('photo', None), 
bio=request.POST.get('bio', None).save()
```

Si quieres guardar un dato, lo recoges del request, en caso de no querer guardarlo pones None o False si es un campo boolean.

Espero que te ayude, si esto no es lo que necesitas, explícalo mejor e intentare ayudarte.

Te dejo un enlace con la documentación de Django y el uso de formularios.

[Info forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/)